# Extract class from lat&lon GeoTIFF using rasterio

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, land-cover

I would like to extract the coverland class from all available coordinates from a GeoTIFF downloaded from ESA website.

I can get a JSON structure with the polygon coordinates.
This is the code:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp

with rasterio.open('ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_N39E000_Map.tif') as dataset:

    # Read the dataset's valid data mask as a ndarray.
    mask = dataset.dataset_mask()

    # Extract feature shapes and values from the array.
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(
            mask, transform=dataset.transform):

        # Transform shapes from the dataset's own coordinate
        # reference system to CRS84 (EPSG:4326).
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
            dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6)

        # Print GeoJSON shapes to stdout.
        #print(geom)
```

Using:

```
for item in geom.items():
  print(item)
```

I can get the image coordinates. How can I get the type of class from each coordinate? Supposedly, there are 11 classes.